# Mount HAR using HDFS-Fuse

Tags: hadoop, har

Is it possible to mount a Hadoop Archive File when using hdfs-fuse-dfs?

I followed the notes on Cloudera for setting up hdfs-fuse-dfs and am able to mount hdfs. I can view hdfs as expected. However, on our HDFS we have .har files. Within hdfs-fuse-dfs I can see the .har files, but I am not able to access the files within (aside from viewing a part-0, _index, etc files).